# Need help loading sjPlot package in R

Tags: r, glm, sjplot

I am trying to use the plot_model function to fit a GLM. I am able to install sjPlot using the install.packages function. However, when I use library(sjPlot), I get this:

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘sjPlot’ in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], 
c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):
     namespace ‘tibble’ 1.4.2 is already loaded, but >= 2.0.0 is required
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried updating your packages as suggested [here](https://github.com/strengejacke/sjPlot/issues/374)?

Try running: 
`update.packages()`

And then re-loading the library:
`library(sjPlot)`

Comment: Yes, it looks like one of the packages requires the new version of the _tibble_ package.